# How to tag a docker image with info coming from the dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, appveyor

I am building a docker image with the vs2017 build tools in it and I would like to tag the image with a version number made of the various version number of is constituant. Like BuildToolsVer, windowsSDKVer,...

I can get the build tools version like this in the dockerfile

```
RUN (get-item C:\\TEMP\\vs_buildtools.exe).VersionInfo | % FileVersion
```

But I don't know how I can "export" this version number to the host that is building the image ( build on appveyor).

What is the good way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it outside of your Dockerfile. Run that script and get the version and pass it to the `docker build` command.

Not familiar with appveyor. If you don't have access to `docker build` command, there may be a way to pass the version to the docker step

On a quick glance on the google results, I see

```
build_script:
  - docker build -t me/myfavoriteapp .
```

https://stefanscherer.github.io/setup-windows-docker-ci-appveyor/

Comment: Ya I know i could do that, but it would be best is i could just call it once.
Because it if not it would imply to download the installer twice. And can be error prone.

Comment: Also i want to build the version from multiple version numbers soit would be weird to pass all the path to download and install in the build args...

Comment: I saw someplace saving things to a file, maybe save thing to a file during the build then docker cp to host the file and read the version from the file?